# How can I convert a 2-D table into a grid in Excel or MS Access

Tags: excel, ms-access

I have 3 tables:

```
Room A
Room B
Room C
```

```
8:00
9:00
10:00
11:00
```

```
Kathy   Room A  9:00
John    Room C  8:00
DaVon   Room C  10:00
Janelly Room A  10:00
```

I want to create a grid using Table A for Rows and Table B for Columns, like so:

```
        8:00    9:00    10:00    11:00
Room A          Kathy   Janelly
Room B
Room C  John            DaVon
```

I'd prefer using the query designer if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider for Access:

Query1: This is a CROSSTAB query

```
TRANSFORM First(Schedule.Person) AS FirstOfPerson
SELECT Schedule.Room
FROM Hours LEFT JOIN Schedule ON Hours.Hr = Schedule.Hr
GROUP BY Schedule.Room
PIVOT Hours.Hr;
```

Query2:

```
SELECT Rooms.Room, Query1.*
FROM Query1 RIGHT JOIN Rooms ON Query1.Room = Rooms.Room;
```

Comment: That was it. It did exactly what I wanted. Thank you SO much. It would have taken me a long time to figure that one out. I am very impressed. Nice job.